# How to lookup coordinates on google maps directions api response?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, google-directions-api

Is there any api or way of checking if a coordinate or location exist in the returned Direction Api response?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponses

I want to check if the returned Direction Api response contains my hardcoded coordinate/location?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the API:

The DirectionsRoute returns the overview_path (array of the lat/lng). With this, you can create a Polyline. And you can use this Polyline to call google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge function

If you use the WebService:

The returned JSON have a overview_polyline key. You can use it to create the Polyline and call google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge function

Regards

Comment: Thanks @Cadetill, i got it to work with PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(latLng, latLngs, false, 2);